# Bind with jquery works only once

Tags: jquery, bind

Here you can see my code :

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('ok');
});
```

The first time I click on my submit button, i have "ok" in my console, so no problem.

But if i click again, i can't see the text "ok" in my console.

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you show more code? The problem probably is somewhere else.

Comment: i have try your code, its working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome at least, "ok" will not appear under the first one, it will simply be shown to the left of it as `(2)` with a red background and increase each time...